# Spring Batch Admin - Override configurations are not recognized

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch-admin

I have downloaded the spring-batch-admin 1.3.0.RELEASE project, and updated all of the library references to the most recent RELEASE versions so that they are compatible with my spring-batch environment (eg. spring-xxx 4.1.4.RELEASE).

I have applied the environment settings and overrides per http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/getting-started.html .  However, those overrides are not being recognized.

At least one email chain linked this symptom to the jira issues linked to https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12111 , but those are allegedly fixed in spring core 4.1 .

Since the problem appears to be that the XML files in the project are not being scanned at all (only the ones embedded in the jar files), it seems to me that here should be some obvious way to work around this, even if it is not technically a "fix".

I am open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by downloading the latest 1.3.1.RELEASE source from github and building it without any modifications.